# What is the logic of running a NiMH battery in charge-discharge cycles everyday?

Tags: batteries, aviation-electronics

I have an 1500 mAh NiMH battery for powering a 2250 kV motor and four 9g servos for my radio controlled plane.

I had bought the battery 8 months back and I had used it to fly my plane which drained my battery after 20 minutes and 8 months hence when I drain it, it runs for like 9 minutes. So I haven't used it during that span of 8 months nor have I charged it.

After a lot of googling and research as to why that happened, the reason I got was that I should be running my battery on charge - discharge cycles everyday but didn't get any answer as to why we have to run it.

Comment: "Charge/discharge" every day actually sounds like a really good way to DESTROY a battery.  Most batteries are only rated for a limited number of charge/discharge cycles.  Doing that every day seems like it would shorten the battery's life to no advantage.

Comment: Is your question about why it is suggested that you do a discharge/charge cycle every day?  If yes, then this is to fight against a memory effect of the batteries.  Many sources state however that nowadays memory effects are negligeable.  Your problem might be different: if you discharge your batteries too much (while using them normally), you also risk damaging them.  The discharge/charge cycle of the RC charger will limit the discharge voltage, but your plane not neccessarilly.

Comment: Ok... if it's right to ask....what other factors effect the efficiency with respect to time?... Is it only because of memory effect?

Comment: For NiMH, I would not expect more than 300 cycles.

Comment: Winny, you have spelled minutes wrong ^^. Forth line down.

Comment: *Is it only because of memory effect?* NimH cells generally have very little memory effect. Do note that NiMh cell performance is also related to manufacturer, the model and the cell's nominal capacity. I have **very** (>15 years) old Philips cells that are still performing better than more modern cells with more mAhrs crammed into them.

Comment: Another thing to consider is the manufacturer's stated discharge rate for the cells.  If you discharge them faster than they are designed for (higher discharge current that rated) then you will permanently and irreversably damage the cells.   The internal resistance rises, so that you can no longer draw high current from them.

Comment: @TestDeviant you've spelt "fourth", "lose" and "it's" wrong so let's not go down that path, eh?

Comment: That's why I don't edit people's posts, i'm not great in that field, worse than others. It was supposed to be a gentle pointer I guess.

Comment: @TestDeviant You need to put @ username, or he/she won't be informed.

Comment: Can you add a link or two that refer you to this recommended charge/discharge cycle? As others have mentioned, there's no memory effect in NiMH that's an effect that the related NiCd batteries have to deal with which do need regular charge/discharge cycles. Are you sure you haven't confused the two battery chemistries?

Comment: @horta It's pretty much an urban myth that NiCd batteries experience memory effect. Google it. NASA has experienced it in a temperature and precision controlled enviorment but it's highly unlikley a consumer or end user will. They are crap compared to Li-Ion non the less.

Comment: @winny The "memory effect" is a misnomer, sure. It's typically used to describe the very real effect of crystallization on the plates. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_effect#Voltage_depression_due_to_long-term_over-charging

Answer (score 1):

*I should be running my battery on charge - discharge cycles everyday*

That's **bad** advice. As mentioned in the comments, for most cells, including NiMh cells, the number of cycles they go through determines a large part of their service life. For many NiMh cells this is often stated to be 1000 cycles.

If you would cycle every day then the cells might be worn out after only three years. The 1000 cycles is usually only valid when the cells are charged and discharged at a nominal (low) current like C/10. So for a 1500 mAh cell that's 150 mA. Then charging and discharging lasts a full day. If you use a higher current to make this go faster, you might not reach the 1000 cycles as the cell will wear out sooner.

For long-term storage of NiMh cells I think the best solution is to either trickle charge (with a very small current) the cells to keep them full or just let the cells discharge and charge them only before use.

Answer (score 0):

NiMH batteries tend to have a higher self discharge then other technologies (they loose their charge even when not in use), hence why its advised to cycle them regularly. Every day seems very excessive, unless you have a daily use of them of course.

I would advise to charge and discharge at least once a month. That's what I try to do, I don't notice cells going much less than 1.2V in that amount of time.

Comment: I do not think this is very good advice. NiMh cells can handle a complete discharge (unlike Li-Ion based cells) and can fully recover from being stored without any charge. Cycling the batteries every month will limit their service life. Not that much but still. The best solution is to either **trickle charge** (with a very small current) the cells to keep them full or just let the cells discharge and charge them only before use.

Comment: To trickle charge is certainly no bad idea, but it all depends on how often people use cells. For me its nearly every day, so inherently I may as well charge them back up in good time. Perhaps the at least once a month is questionable, but when I used to have cells lying around for >6 months, some of them are very dead now.

Comment: *some of them are very dead now.* Just charge them again and if they are any good they will just work. You could also get some LSD (Low Self Discharge) NiMh cells like Eneloop, GP ReCyCo etc. These will keep most of their charge even after many months.

Comment: Yes, by dead I mean don't hold charge at all well. I went for Uniross years ago. But most of those self discharge a lot quicker then my other cheap unbranded cells.

Comment: I also have some Uniross, bought them because they were supposed to be good. Indeed they have high self leakage. So I switched to GP ReCyKo, they perform reasonably well. I have yet to try the Ikea ones (the more expensive white ones, not the brown ones), I read somewhere that these are actually the same model as Eneloop but much cheaper. I have some Eneloop, these perform well.

Answer (score 0):

Eneloop, Energizer and Duracell sell Ni-MH batteries that hold their charge for one year so you do not need to trickle charge them and do not need to frequently charge them.